# Import .glb file into Unity from Solidworks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, file-format, solidworks, htc-vive

Using the following [documentation](https://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/whatsnew/t_export_using_extended_reality.htm), I was able to export a solidworks file into both .glb or .gltf file formats. According to the Solidworks documentation you should be able to then import these 3D models into Unity.

When I go into the Unity assets folder and click import new asset, the file won't even show up in the dialog. Is there some special workflow I need to do in order to import .glb or .gltf files into Unity?

Am I missing something or is the Solidworks documentation incorrect?

I can drag the file into the assets window but it is unusable in the project.
[image]

All I want to be able to do is view this solid works 3D file within Unity. Eventually I want to be able to view the 3D object on my HTC Vive.

Comment: According to https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html that file format doesnt seem to be supported, how I read it is the default file extension might be

Answer (score 1):

Unity supports .FBX files the best. I am not a user of Solidworks myself but i heard that this plugin could help you export .FBX models from Solidworks:
https://www.simlab-soft.com/3d-plugins/SolidWorks/fbx_exporter_for_SolidWorks-main.aspx